# How to find a spanning tree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization

The question is:

> Describe how you can find a spanning tree for which
>   (a) the product of the edge-costs is minimal
>   (b) the maximum of the edge-costs is minimal

Somebody has told me to use Jarnik-Prim Algorithm,but I still don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you actually read what Prim's algorithm does? It's probably the simplest algorithm for efficiently solving the minimal spanning tree problem

Comment: Hint :

a) Use the fact that $\ln(a b) = \ln a + \ln b$